# Not concatenating content with classes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, selector, concatenation

jQuery noob here (don't most posts start like that?)

I know I could do this with CSS alone however, just to make the experience a little more tactile, I'm trying to write a jQuery "spoiler" function that obfuscates a bit of text on a page if it's marked up appropriately and reveals it on mouseover.

On the whole this works nicely - it replaces the text with some text of your choice and even matches the width of the replaced text to stop the text from reflowing. The problem comes when I add more than one spoiler class on a page - in this case it concatenates the text within each spoiler and seems to match the width of the element first matched element. It's basically like the function can't tell the difference between each spoiler so it puts them all together.

I must be doing something wrong on a fairly fundamental level. Can someone point out my mistake please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Spoiler test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery.fn.spoiler = function(spoilerReplaceText) {
        $(this).addClass('spoilerCensored');
        var spoilerText = $(this).text();
        var spoilerWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).attr('spoilertext',spoilerText).text(spoilerReplaceText).width(spoilerWidth);
        $(this).stop().hover(
            function(){
                var spoilerText = $(this).attr('spoilertext');
                $(this).fadeOut(250,function(){
                    $(this).text(spoilerText).addClass('spoilerRevealed').removeClass('spoilerCensored').fadeIn(250);
                });
            },
            function(){
                $(this).fadeOut(250,function(){
                    $(this).text(spoilerReplaceText).removeClass('spoilerRevealed').addClass('spoilerCensored').fadeIn(250);
                });
            }
        );
    };

    $('.spoiler').spoiler("don't touch this");
});

</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .spoiler {display: inline-block;background-color: #000000;color: #000000;text-align: center;}
    .spoilerCensored {color: #ffffff;}
    .spoilerRevealed {background-color: #ffffff;color: #000000;}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<p>You can add a <span class="spoiler">spoiler to your content</span> very easily. All you need to do is <span class="spoiler">add a class called spoiler to each bit of text</span> you'd like to hide. There is a problem with <span class="spoiler">adding</span> more than one spoiler to a page though.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The easiest way to obfuscate "spoiler text" is just to make it the same color as the background, and toggle that on rollover. Scrambling the text itself seems like overkill.

Comment: I agree, but this excercie was more a challenge for me than a proper commercial project. What I wanted to achieve was to not simply blank out the obfuscated text but to allow the user to be able to define the text that showed instead - for that reason this works quite well. I don't know if it's the best method though :) I'm sure an XHTML validator would scream at me for some of the techniques I've used!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to treat the argument as a set:

```
$.fn.spoiler = function() {
   this.each(function(){
      // yur current code
   });

  return this;
}
```

If youre using this as plugin which is essentially what you have done you also do want that snippet of code inside document ready. You want it in its own js file which you include just after jquery.

You also might want to add options/defaults:

```
$.fn.spoiler = function(options) {
   var o = $.extend($.fn.spoiler.defaults, options||{});

   this.each(function(){
      // yur current code
      // reference the replacement text with o.text
   });

  return this;
}

$.fn.spoiler.defaults = {
   "text": 'Spoiler Alert'
};
```

And your usage then becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.spoiler').spoiler({
      'text': 'Custom text'
   });
});
```

Check out the [plugin authoring docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) for more info

Comment: You guys are great - thank you! A understand about the whole each thing - I know my way around php. The extend thing though is a little bit out of my comfort zone at the moment, however it's been duly noted and hopefully it'll make more sense in the fullness of time. Cheers guys!

Comment: @doug: `$.extend` is kinda like `array_merge` on an associative array in PHP.

Comment: Ah, I see. That will allow me to look at it in a different light - thanks prodigitalson.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery object you're operating on is sometimes a set of DOM elements, and your function is operating on all of them at once. With methods like `.addClass` this isn't a problem, because they operate on each DOM element individually and return the modified jQuery object for chaining. `.text`, on the other hand, is not chainable -- it combines the results of all DOM elements it finds and returns a single string.

To solve this, try adding an `.each` loop (untested):

```
jQuery.fn.spoiler = function(spoilerReplaceText) {
    $(this).each(function(i,el) {
        $(el).addClass('spoilerCensored');
        var spoilerText = $(el).text();
        var spoilerWidth = $(el).width();
        ...
```

and so on. Notice that inside the `.each` I replaced `this` with `el` at each point. (Technically you should be able to keep using `this`, but I find it confusing when there's more than one `this` floating around.)